Resolver not using custom database connection for multitenancy
I have this resolver which is creating all the endpoints and mutations (without having to specify one by one) but for the autogenerated ones it's using the default connection not the custom one I am using in service class. I am looking for a way to configure the connection here but haven't had any luck. Any help would be appreciated.
@Resolver(() => Assessment)
export class AssessmentResolver {
    constructor(private assessmentService: AssessmentService) { }

    @Query(() => AssessmentConnection)
    @UsePermission(PermissionEnum.VIEW_ASSESSMENTS)
    async assessments(
        @Args({ type: () => AssessmentQuery }) query: AssessmentQuery,
        @CurrentUser() currentUser: User,
    ): Promise<ConnectionType<Assessment>> {
        return this.assessmentService.getAssessments(query, currentUser);
    }

}

and this is my service class
import { CONNECTION } from 'src/modules/tenancy/tenancy.symbols';
import { TypeOrmQueryService } from '@nestjs-query/query-typeorm';
import { QueryService } from '@nestjs-query/core';
@QueryService(Assessment)
export class AssessmentService extends TypeOrmQueryService<Assessment> {
    private assessmentRepository: Repository<Assessment>;
    private userRepository: Repository<User>;
    private assessmentTypeRepo: Repository<AssessmentType>;

    constructor(
        @Inject(CONNECTION) private connection,
    ) {
        super(connection.getRepository(Assessment));
        this.assessmentRepository = this.connection.getRepository(Assessment);
        this.userRepository = this.connection.getRepository(User);
        this.assessmentTypeRepo = this.connection.getRepository(AssessmentType);
    }
}

